# I want to make a chat record in the real chat. on react

Tags: reactjs, websocket

I am making chat web by react.
He's using socket.io
Obtain values in an array and print data through the map.
However, instead of maintaining the value you received before, it simply changes to a different value.
I want the new value to be stamped when the price remains and the value is changed to another value.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
  import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
  import "./App.css";

  class App extends Component {
    constructor() {
      super();
      this.state = {
        endpoint: "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000/",

        text: '',
        log: [

        ]
      };
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
      this.setState({
        [e.target.name]: e.target.value
      })
    }


    send = () => {
      const socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint);
      socket.emit('change color', this.state.text);
    }




    render() {


      const socket = socketIOClient(this.state.endpoint);
      socket.on('change color', (col) => {
        this.setState({
          log : col
        })
      })

      return (
          <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>


            <input placeholder={'입력칸'} type={'text'} name={'text'} onChange={this.handleChange}/>
            <button onClick={() => this.send()}>전송하기</button>
            <ul id={'log'}>
              {this.state.log.map((contact, i) => {
                return (<LogInfo name={contact.name} message={contact.message} key={i} />);
              })}
            </ul>
          </div>
      )
    }
  }

  class LogInfo extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return(
          <li>{this.props.name} {this.props.message}</li>
      );
    }
  }

  export default App;
```

response is log:[ message:foo ]

Answer (score 0):

When you receive a `change color` event, you're currently replacing `this.state.log` by what you receive, I suppose what you want is to add what you receive to your `log` array:

```
socket.on('change color', (col) => {
  this.setState({
    log: [
      ...this.state.log,
      col
    ]
  })
})
```

By the way, there are a lot of things wrong in your code snippet:

```
this.state = {
  endpoint: "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:3000/",
};
```

Your endpoint should probably not live in your state unless changing it should trigger a re-render of your component.

You should instantiate your socket and your socket events once in your constructor:

```
constructor () {
  this.socket = socketIOClient('http://xx.xxx.xxx.xx:3000/');
  this.socket.on('change color', () => {
    // Do something
  });
}

send = () => {
  this.socket.emit('change color', this.state.text);
}
```

and not every time in your render function.